# Analysing memory dump after BSOD - 0xC0000147

Tags: bsod, machine-check-exception

My computer (HP DV6 6060EP) was returned to repair by HP  twice, but it still comes with the same problem.
I'm trying the best i can to help them diagnose this problem.

When my computer crashes (like it did 5 mins ago), after opening the Memory dump in WinDbg i get the following result:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\hp\Desktop\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Summary Dump File: Only kernel address space is available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Missing image name, possible paged-out or corrupt data.
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for Unknown_Module_00000000`00000000
Unable to add module at 00000000`00000000
WARNING: .reload failed, module list may be incomplete
Debugger can not determine kernel base address
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7600 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 7600.16617.amd64fre.win7_gdr.100618-1621
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`02e4c000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`03089e50
Debug session time: Mon Jul 30 21:00:15.549 2012 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:02:45.611
Missing image name, possible paged-out or corrupt data.
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for Unknown_Module_00000000`00000000
Unable to add module at 00000000`00000000
WARNING: .reload failed, module list may be incomplete
Debugger can not determine kernel base address
Loading Kernel Symbols
Missing image name, possible paged-out or corrupt data.
.*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for Unknown_Module_00000000`00000000
Unable to add module at 00000000`00000000
Unable to read KLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY at 00000000`00000000 - NTSTATUS 0xC0000147

WARNING: .reload failed, module list may be incomplete
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 9C, {0, fffff8800316cc70, 0, 0}

***** Debugger could not find nt in module list, module list might be corrupt, error 0x80070057.

Probably caused by : Unknown_Image ( ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION (9c)
A fatal Machine Check Exception has occurred.
KeBugCheckEx parameters;
    x86 Processors
        If the processor has ONLY MCE feature available (For example Intel
        Pentium), the parameters are:
        1 - Low  32 bits of P5_MC_TYPE MSR
        2 - Address of MCA_EXCEPTION structure
        3 - High 32 bits of P5_MC_ADDR MSR
        4 - Low  32 bits of P5_MC_ADDR MSR
        If the processor also has MCA feature available (For example Intel
        Pentium Pro), the parameters are:
        1 - Bank number
        2 - Address of MCA_EXCEPTION structure
        3 - High 32 bits of MCi_STATUS MSR for the MCA bank that had the error
        4 - Low  32 bits of MCi_STATUS MSR for the MCA bank that had the error
    IA64 Processors
        1 - Bugcheck Type
            1 - MCA_ASSERT
            2 - MCA_GET_STATEINFO
                SAL returned an error for SAL_GET_STATEINFO while processing MCA.
            3 - MCA_CLEAR_STATEINFO
                SAL returned an error for SAL_CLEAR_STATEINFO while processing MCA.
            4 - MCA_FATAL
                FW reported a fatal MCA.
            5 - MCA_NONFATAL
                SAL reported a recoverable MCA and we don't support currently
                support recovery or SAL generated an MCA and then couldn't
                produce an error record.
            0xB - INIT_ASSERT
            0xC - INIT_GET_STATEINFO
                  SAL returned an error for SAL_GET_STATEINFO while processing INIT event.
            0xD - INIT_CLEAR_STATEINFO
                  SAL returned an error for SAL_CLEAR_STATEINFO while processing INIT event.
            0xE - INIT_FATAL
                  Not used.
        2 - Address of log
        3 - Size of log
        4 - Error code in the case of x_GET_STATEINFO or x_CLEAR_STATEINFO
    AMD64 Processors
        1 - Bank number
        2 - Address of MCA_EXCEPTION structure
        3 - High 32 bits of MCi_STATUS MSR for the MCA bank that had the error
        4 - Low  32 bits of MCi_STATUS MSR for the MCA bank that had the error
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000
Arg2: fffff8800316cc70
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

***** Debugger could not find nt in module list, module list might be corrupt, error 0x80070057.


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9C_GenuineIntel

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002e156e0 to fffff80002ebc740

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`0316cc38 fffff800`02e156e0 : 00000000`0000009c 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0316cc70 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffff800`02ebc740
fffff880`0316cc40 00000000`0000009c : 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0316cc70 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffff800`02e156e0
fffff880`0316cc48 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`0316cc70 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x9c


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Unknown_Module

IMAGE_NAME:  Unknown_Image

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

BUCKET_ID:  CORRUPT_MODULELIST

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Does anyone have an idea of what my be happening ? They already switched the motherboard and harddrive.

Thanks!

Comment: I have not used any of them so I would hesitate to post it as an answer, but there are a plethora of crash dump analysis tools available on the internet. Have you tried any of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the full kernel dump wasn't providing me enough details so i changed the settings to small memory dumps.

After checking the dump with WinDbg i was able to see that intelpp.sys was showing as the culprit, so it was clear that the cause of the BSOD was the CPU.